# Can webpack-dev-server run on a unix domain sockets?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

We have a central server on which we host the environments of all our developers. We have nginx running which proxies requests to uwsgi application servers.

We have now started using webpack and we will end up running webpack-dev-server per developer. What I want to do is make webpack-dev-server run on a unix socket (so that we are not eating up ports) and proxy all the requests to this webpack-dev-server via nginx.

I was looking at the webpack-dev-server code on github and noticed that it accepts only a host and port as options.

Has anyone tried doing this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but if you pass the socket path as the `--port` argument it should work.

**Example:**
`webpack-dev-server --port tmp/webpack_socket`

It works because port is the first parameter passed to `server.listen`. Here's a snippet from the [webpack-dev-server.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/bin/webpack-dev-server.js) file where the server is started:

```
new Server(...).listen(options.port, options.host, function(err) {
  ...
});
```